# How to automatically destroy a dialog component? like(autoHideDuration)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I used Material-ui's Dialogue component in a similar way to Popup. But I want it to stay on the screen for a while. How do I set this? I'm looking for a feature like auto hide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a basic MUI Dialog component:

```
<Dialog 
    open={this.state.open ? true : false} 
    onClose={this.handleClose}  
    aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title" 
    aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description" 
    disableBackdropClick 
> 
    //content...
</Dialog>
```

this.state.open decides whether the Dialog is open or not.
To open a dialog, you are probably already setting open to be true at some point. In the same setState function you can add a timeout to hide the dialog.

Example:

```
this.setState({
    open:true
  },
  ()=>{
    setTimeout(function () {
        this.setState({open:false})
    }, 5000);//5 Second delay   
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: But this is not the right way. Cz once you open the modal, it will set to autoclose to 5 seconds. But during that time, if you manually close it and open during this time ( eg 3rd second ), this will autoclose immediately without waiting the next 5 seconds.

Comment: @MishhubMohammed - If you want to handle the edge case you mentioned it is as simple as copying the same code and clearing the timeout by handling the onClose event.

Answer (score 0):

Hide is not destroy.

```
const Login: FunctionComponent<Props> = (props) => {
const [should_open, set_should_open] = useState(true);
const { is_login } = useRecoilValue(user_info_state);

// ! logout function
const reset_user_info = useResetRecoilState(user_info_state);

return (
    <Wrapper {...props}>
        <StyledButton onClick={() => (is_login ? reset_user_info() : set_should_open(true))}>
            {is_login ? (
                <>
                    LogOut
                    <img src={airplanemode_inactive} alt='login' />
                </>
            ) : (
                <>
                    Login
                    <img src={airplanemode_active} alt='log_out' />
                </>
            )}
        </StyledButton>
        {is_login ? '' : <LoginModal should_open={should_open} set_should_open={set_should_open} />}
    </Wrapper>
);
```

};

you can destroy modal comp depends on status of state

Answer (score 0):

This is how i handle autoClose in material ui modals

```html
const [isModalVisible, setIsModalVisible] = useState(open);
const [timer, setTimer] = useState(null);

    const handleOpen = () => {
        setIsModalVisible(true);
        setTimer(
            setTimeout(() => {
                setIsModalVisible(false);
            }, 5000)
        );
    };

    const handleClose = () => {
        if (reason === "escapeKeyDown" || reason === "backdropClick") {
            setIsModalVisible(false);
            timer && clearTimeout(timer);
        }
    };
```